# Input 0 of layer max_pooling2d_15 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=7. Full shape received: (None, 100, 100, 1, 1, 1, 96)

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, neural-network, computer-vision

I am working on a computer vision project, for input i have 6 classes each containing gray images with otsu's thresholding method applied of size (224,224) and i have trained the model and stored it in RecogModel.tfl file here is the model i am using.

```
model = Sequential()
# 1st Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=96, input_shape=(224,224,1), kernel_size=(11,11),strides=(4,4), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Pooling 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same'))
# Batch Normalisation before passing it to the next layer
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# 2nd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(1,1), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same'))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# 3rd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# 4th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# 5th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same'))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# Passing it to a dense layer
model.add(Flatten())
# 1st Dense Layer
model.add(Dense(8192, input_shape=(224*224*3,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout to prevent overfitting
model.add(Dropout(0.7))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# 2nd Dense Layer
model.add(Dense(8192))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.7))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# 3rd Dense Layer
model.add(Dense(4096))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.6))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# Output Layer
model.add(Dense(6))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.summary()
```

As I use gray image

```
import tensorflow as tf
X_train = tf.expand_dims(X_train, axis=-1)
X_train = tf.cast(X_train, tf.float32) / 255.0

X_valid = tf.expand_dims(X_valid, axis=-1)
X_valid = tf.cast(X_valid, tf.float32) / 255.0

X_test = tf.expand_dims(X_test, axis=-1)
X_test = tf.cast(X_test, tf.float32) / 255.0

sgd = SGD(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("Checkpoint/weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5", monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=False, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
# (5) Train
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=1, verbose=1,validation_data=(X_valid,Y_valid), shuffle=True,callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

When i run the code i get this error

> ```
>  ValueError: Input 0 of layer max_pooling2d_15 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=7. Full shape received:(None, 100, 100, 1, 1, 1, 96)
> ```

CODE

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from PIL import Image 

use = input("Are you using mobile or laptop(y)")

if use == 'y':

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://193.154.32.3:8080/video')
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model("RecogModel1.tfl")
    minValue = 70

    while(True):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1) 
        clone = frame.copy()
        '''draw box
        https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-rectangle-method/
        '''
        start_point = (400, 100)
        end_point = (650, 340)
        color = (255, 0, 0) 
        thickness = 2
        image = cv2.rectangle(frame, start_point, end_point, color, thickness) 

        '''crp only required region
        https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-crop-an-image-using-the-numpy-module/
        '''
        image_arr = np.array(image)     
        image_arr = image_arr[100:400, 340:650]
        image_arr = cv2.resize(image_arr,(224, 224))

    #     '''preprocess image
    #     ex). gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  #converting to grayscale
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_arr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),2)

        th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,2)
        ret, res = cv2.threshold(th3, minValue, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    #     '''

        #prediction
        #fimg = tf.expand_dims(res, axis=0)
        #fimg = tf.expand_dims(fimg, axis=-1)
        prediction = model.predict(fimg)
        predictedClass = np.argmax(prediction)
        confidence = prediction[0][predictedClass]
        #confidence = (np.amax(prediction) / (prediction[0][0] + prediction[0][1] + prediction[0][2]))
        stat(predictedClass, confidence)


    #     preprocessed_img=np.uint8(preprocessed_img)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame1', res)
    #     cv2.imshow('frame1',  preprocessed_img))
    #     print(predictedClass," ",confidence)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
            break

    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
else:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model("RecogModel1.tfl")
    minValue = 70

    while(True):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1) 
        clone = frame.copy()
        '''draw box
        https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-rectangle-method/
        '''
        start_point = (400, 100)
        end_point = (650, 340)
        color = (255, 0, 0) 
        thickness = 2
        image = cv2.rectangle(frame, start_point, end_point, color, thickness) 

        '''crp only required region
        https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-crop-an-image-using-the-numpy-module/
        '''
        image_arr = np.array(image)     
        image_arr = image_arr[100:400, 340:650]
        image_arr = cv2.resize(image_arr,(224, 224))

    #     '''preprocess image
    #     ex). gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  #converting to grayscale
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_arr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),2)

        th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,2)
        ret, res = cv2.threshold(th3, minValue, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    #     '''

        #prediction
#         fimg = tf.expand_dims(res, axis=0)
#         fimg = tf.expand_dims(fimg, axis=-1)
        prediction = model.predict(fimg)
        predictedClass = np.argmax(prediction)
        confidence = prediction[0][predictedClass]
        #confidence = (np.amax(prediction) / (prediction[0][0] + prediction[0][1] + prediction[0][2]))
        stat(predictedClass, confidence)


    #     preprocessed_img=np.uint8(preprocessed_img)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame1', res)
    #     cv2.imshow('frame1',  preprocessed_img))
    #     print(predictedClass," ",confidence)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
            break

    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64631876/input-0-of-layer-max-pooling2d-is-incompatible-with-the-layer-expected-ndim-4) may be, probably, helpful.