# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "max_pooling2d" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

This is my code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 2), activation = "relu", input_shape = (400, 600, 900, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2, 2))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = "relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2, 2))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(540))

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy() , metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(images, masks, batch_size=30, epochs = 5)
```

I have a simple CNN model which takes in 400 images of sizes 600 x 900 with 3 color channels for RGB, and my corresponding outputs are 400 images of size 600 x 900 (no color channels as its greyscale).

I keep getting errors when I run compile the model, my terminal instantly kills the process each time the code reaches the first Dense layer, before that CPU and GPU usage wasnt particularly high, Ive also tried it on Google Colab to monitor the RAM usage and it was perfectly below the threshold level before it reaches the Dense layer.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64631876/input-0-of-layer-max-pooling2d-is-incompatible-with-the-layer-expected-ndim-4

Comment: Yes I did, I am using that format for my input_shape, so it shouldn't be the issue here

Comment: Try `input_shape = (600, 900, 3)`.

Comment: The samples dimension is not part of the input shape

Comment: You shouldn't include <number of images> to `input_shape` arg. `input_shape` should contain a shape of images you're going to use in your model